# java programming (convert from integer to string)

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, integer

I'm trying to convert from integer to string to read in a sequence of digits in a string. The input needs to be one string each time, not one integer. the number that will be stored in an arraylist should not be integer but a string.

```
//wbin

//ow
```

int count = 0;
int total = 0;

final int SENTINEL = 0;

int score;
`

```
int sum;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System in);
ArrayList list = new Array();
System.out.println("Enter your digits");
System.out.println("Enter 0 to calculate");
score = scan.nextint();
while ( score !=SENTINEL)
{ total  = score + total;
list.add(score);
count++;
System.out.println("next number");
score = scan.nextint();
}
if (count != 0)
{
DecimalFormat oneDecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat( "##.0" );
System.out.println("\nYour Average is "                         
+ oneDecimalPlace.format( (double) ( total / count) ) );        
System.out.println("Your Total is " + total);




for (int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
else
System.out.println( "\nNo digits were entered" );
```

Comment: Please indent your code and cut away the code that is not relevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList list = new Array();
```

why don't you use an ArrayList of Strings?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

-

```
score = scan.nextint();
```

why don't you ask for the next line instead of the next int?

```
score = scan.nextLine();
```

That would solve your question, but, if you are doing arithmetic operations to those numbers why would you want to store them as Strings in the first place? you will end up concatenating Strings when you are supposed to add up the score to the total.

Answer (score 0):

String s = Integer.toString(n); or  String s = "" + n; 
this code will give you integer to string conversion.